# Duplicate of Entity

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

I am not able to get this working and I find no example for my special case. In short words: I have a main entity with relationships. Now I want to make a copy of a sub-entity and link this new sub-entity to the main entity. Best I try to make a short example. I skip the getter and setter methods to make it shorter:

Entity Entry:

```
@Entity
public class Entry implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entry", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EntryData> entriesDataList = new LinkedList<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private EntryData entryData;

}
```

Entity EntryData:

```
@Entity
public class EntryData implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String subject;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Entry entry;    

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "entries", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
    private List<EntryTag> tags = new LinkedList<>();

}
```

Entity EntryTag:

```
@Entity
public class EntryTag  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany() 
    private List<EntryData> entries = new LinkedList<>();        

}
```

**Now I want to do the following:**

```
@Stateless
public class NewEntryData {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void makeNewEntryData(){
        Entry e = em.find(Entry.class, 10);
        em.detach(e);
        EntryData ed = e.getEntryData();
        ed.setSubject("New Subject");
        ed.setId(null);
        for (Iterator<EntryTag> it = ed.getTags().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            it.next().addEntryData(ed);            
        }
        em.merge(e);
    }   
}
```

**What I expected:**

A new Entity `EntryData` is generated which has the same content as the old one which was stored in `Entry.entryData`, except the new subject. In `Entry.entryData` a link to the new `EntryData` is generated. The old `EntryData` consists in the database as it was.

**What I get at `em.merge(e)`:**

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [id] of class [test.EntryData] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
```

Can someone help me how to solve this?

Comment: I am no java developer, but after reading the post I was browsing and saw CascadeDetach which detaches all the navigation objects. Is that relevant to the framework you are using?

Comment: Because of the `CascadeType.ALL` I think that I already do a cascade detach.

Answer (score 1):

Your column `id` of `test.EntryData` class is mapped as primary key, so updates are not allowed in `id column`

I think you are inserting duplicate value in id column

Comment: And what would be the solution to do what I want? It was planned that I change the primary key to `null`. This way I thought I can achieve that a new `EntryData` Entity is generated and not the old one overwritten.

Comment: add auto increment to that column

Comment: I thought `GenerationType.AUTO` will create an id if it is `null`?

Comment: At all I already use auto increment... `GenerationType.AUTO` corresponds to auto increment in MYSQL

Comment: k k create a sequence in your mysql table and modify your code as for example
public class ContactMaster implements Serializable{
 
 
 @TableGenerator(name="CONT_SEQGEN", table="SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", 
 pkColumnName = "SEQ_ID", valueColumnName = "SEQ_ID_VAL", pkColumnValue = "CONTACT_ID", allocationSize = 1)
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE,generator="CONT_SEQGEN")
 @Column(name="CONTACT_ID")
 public String contactId;